# Vue.js app is run on http://localhost:8080, whenever I make a GET request using axios to my back-end API, the localhost gets prepended to the URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have set axios's base URL to be a variable from my .env file like this:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_SERVER_API
```

And this is the `.env` variable `VUE_APP_SERVER_API="http://lolapi.example.com/api"`

Whenever I make a GET request like this:

```
axios.get('/' + action + 'Summoner/' + trimmedSummoner)
```

The request goes to the wrong URL. It tries to GET from this URL:

`http://localhost:8080/summoner/lolapi.example.com/api/getSummoner/TheOnyxKing`

instead of this one:

```
http://lolapi.example.com/api/getSummoner/TheOnyxKing
```

If I hardcode the correct URL in the GET request, everything works fine:

```
axios.get('http://lolapi.kabzamalov.com/api/getSummoner/TheOnyxKing')
```

Any clue why is this happening? Also this doesn't happen if I build the Vue.js project, it only happens during development.

Comment: I assume you have logged `process.env.VUE_APP_SERVER_API` and `axios.defaults.baseURL` yet to see whether they really contain what you expect them to contain?

Comment: `axios.get('/'` I assume the leading `'/'` is causing your problem because it signals a local URL.

Comment: Both are returning lolapi.example.com/api

Comment: That slash is meant to go between lolapi.example.com/api and getSummoner of my complete URL. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: I also forgot to mention that this error doesn't exists if I build the Vue.js project, it only happens during development.

Comment: Have you tried removing the leading `/`? That is, just keep the statement as `axios.get(action + 'Summoner/' + trimmedSummoner)` and see if that works

Comment: Just did, still the same result.

Comment: How do you build your app? Webpack? How do you inject Environment variables? Or maybe you generated your project with Vue CLI?

Comment: You are correctly using axios. As @ConstantinGroß suggested, you should double check if the env variable contains the expected value. Take a look at : https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes and make sure you have a recent version of vue-cli.

Comment: The project is Generated with Vue CLI 3. I just type npm run build to build it. The enviroment variable contains the correct URL. I've no clue what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a `vue-cli` app, try setting `publicPath` or `baseUrl` in your production and/or development environment.

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath